# Pyinstaller exe is very large

Tags: python

I built a python script with pyinstaller, but the executable file is very large. The python file is just a simple gui app with gtk. What is the cause for this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing size of pyinstaller exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692213/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe)

Comment: Do you feel that an image is the way to convey a file size?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a virtualenv for your project? Otherwise it will install all libraries instead of the ones really needed by your application.

If you haven't done that execute the following commands:

```
python3 -m venv example-env
source example-env\Scripts\activate
```

Now make sure to install all the libraries using pip3 in this virtualenv.