# pyinstaller executable for simple script is 1.4gb

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I built a Python app - it's very straightforward. A file selection box opens, a user chooses a PDF file, and then the text from the PDF is exported to a CSV.

I packaged this as a .exe from within a virtualenv, I only installed the libraries I'm importing (plus PyMuPDF), and the package is still 1.4GB.

The script:

```
import textract
import csv
import codecs
import fitz
import re
import easygui
from io import open


from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

filename = easygui.fileopenbox()

pdfFileObj = fitz.open(filename)

text =""

for page in pdfFileObj:
    text+= page.getText()
    re.sub(r'\W+', '', text)

if text != "":
    text = text

else: 
    text = textract.process(filename, method='tesseract', language='eng')

tokens = word_tokenize(text)

punctuations = ['(',')',';',':','[',']',',']

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

keywords = [word for word in tokens if not word in stop_words and not word in punctuations]

with open('ar.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    for i in keywords:
        write.writerow([i])
```

Some context:

Within my venv, the entire lib folder is about 400MB. So how do I find out what is being added to the .exe that's making it 1.4GB?

Comment: Is there any error or problem here?

Comment: Try to follow this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692213/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe

Comment: @mtdot Yes that's the post I've read previously. I created a new virtualenv, so I'm not sure why it would ever get to be 1.4gb. These packages should all be lightweight.

Comment: You could try compile the exe importing the packages one by one, and figure out which one is the culprit for increasing the size of your file