# How to convert .py file to .exe file with a smaller file size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe

***N.B.: Please do not lock/delete this question as I did not find any relevant answer.***

I need to convert a `.py` file to `.exe`. I have tried `pyinstaller`, `py2exe`, and `auto_py_to_exe`. Unfortunately, the output files are very big. For example, if I simply convert a python file to `print('Hello world!')`, the output folder becomes 22 MB. The command of `--exclude-module` does not reduce so much.
If I write the same code in `C` and compiled by `Dev-C++`, the file size will be below 1 MB.

So, is there any way to convert the `.py` file to a `.exe` file with a smaller file size?

Comment: PyInstaller will bundle everything that is necessary to run your program, in this case the standard libraries and the interpreter. If you do not want to do that, you need to ensure that on the target machine the requirements (i.e. a Python interpreter) are installed, and run the script directly. There is no way around one way or the other. C code on the other hand is compiled and linked to a platform-specific binary, which only includes the machine code instructions.

Comment: See options to reduce pyinstaller size here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692213/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Thank you for your comments. I understand it now.

Comment: @zvi Thank you, I have already checked that link.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Jan in the comments, pyinstaller bundles everything together that is needed to run the program. So realistically the only to make the file smaller is to make sure the target computer has a python environment. Long story short, if you must use a `.exe` then they are not going to get any smaller unless you re-write it so it needs less external libraries etc.

Comment: you are right. I may need to re-write the code or change the platform.