# Pyinstaller generates .exe of huge filesize

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, executable

My python script (*'file1.py'*) contains a one line print statement.

```
#file1.py
print("python to exe")
```

Pyinstaller library is used and has generated executable file (***'file1.exe'***) for windows

```
pyinstaller --onefile 'file1.py'
```

but the generated file size of *'file1.exe'* was huge say 350+MB. Using a virtual environment as suggested in the link shared by a member reduced the file size . however when another line is added importing pandas library

```
#file1.py
import pandas as pd
print("python to exe")
```

and trying to generate executable the file size increased back to 350+MB.
Any ideas welcome to reduce the file size drastically.

Comment: If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: it was very generalized so looking for specific tips with intuition(if any)

Comment: You won't be able to find any assistance without providing more details

Comment: Let me know what kind of details needed, will add it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: query is revised

Comment: `file1.py` contains just one line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing size of pyinstaller exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692213/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe)

Comment: file1.py contains only one line print statement and no imports or any other statement.

Comment: to reduce size drastically you would have to write in C/C++ instead of Python

Comment: Tried several method as mentioned in the link shared(including venv). it is reducing for single line print statement. However if an additional import pandas library is added then still the file size is 350+MB. Any take on this?

Comment: PyInstaller normally generates ~10MB executable for a simple hello world program. So there must be something wrong in your environment. For me, the smallest size I could ger is 3.39MB.

Comment: @gfdsweds i created a plain virtual env and ran the pyinstaller on a python script containing two lines of code ; import-pandas and a simple print statement. the exe file generated was still 350+MB

Comment: are you using anaconda?

Comment: yes i'm using anaconda