# Is there anyway to reduce the .exe file size made by pyinstaller?

Tags: python, compression, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

So I made a super simple program with 1 import (it being `pysimplegui`) and when i compile it the size is 9 mb? The py file is just 1 kb...

Is there a way to make it be less than 8 mb atleast?

Here is my code:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Test app')]]

window = sg.Window('test app', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing size of pyinstaller exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692213/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe)

Comment: No, it didn't help me a lot since the only package I was importing was pysimplegui.

Answer (score 0):

Cause pyinstaller include a copy of your current python core and additional modules (searching recursively for imports in your files and modules) to your build. Python core .dll has size about 3.5Mb, for example.