# Optimize imports python

Tags: python, optimization

i might be asking something stupid here. right now I'm importing these:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import cv2
import numpy as np
import mediapipe as mp
import math
import sys
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import PIL.Image
import ctypes
import requests
import pytube
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
import webbrowser
```

and the output program has almost 500MB is there any way I can optimize it?

Comment: What do you mean by output program?

Comment: when you use pyinstaller to compile it --onefile or --onedir, has almost 500MB

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do would be to see where these modules are used - if you import a large module like `tkinter` (with *all* its dependencies) for something very small, which you could also do by hand, that might be worth cutting out.

Other modules are so small, that it will hardly ever be worth the time. If you want lean and mean, Python isn't the way to go to begin with. Most compiled languages will allow you to create an installation that has a far smaller footprint, due to the way a compiler can optimise what is included and left out.

Having said that, consider the cost of storage vs. the cost of your time. What are you really saving? If the application will be installed hundreds or even thousands (millions?) of times, it may be worth shaving off a few meg, definitely a few 100. But if it's just you? What is that space worth to you?

Also note that it isn't just the modules you're importing - it's also all their dependencies. Try installing `pip install pipdeptree` and run:

```
pipdeptree
```

Have a look at what is really included in your environment (which would ideally only have the packages you really use actually installed). As user @0x263A correctly points out, [this question answers how to achieve that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692213/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe).

Comment: i got all of these:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkC8JIwVC-FdiMo_lpP4pJeVY1P64w?e=RfnxgT