# Using Module without Library

Tags: python, module

While writing code i only use [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) module from "pandas" library and when i try to make executable my code all pandas library comes with my code so the size of the .exe file become almost 1gb. How can i use only one module from library without import all library. Or any sugggestion ? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing size of pyinstaller exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692213/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe) - Pandas shouldn't be anywhere near 1Gb in size.  It is a big package, but not that big.  It is 63Mb on my system.  I'm on a Mac.  I don't know if that makes any difference for Pandas.  That's still pretty big though, so I hope you find a way to reduce both the Pandas component and whatever else it is that is making your .exe so big.

Comment: Also 63Mb is huge for me i only use "pandas.read_excell()" module. I would likte to use only this module and my .exe file include only this module not all pandas library. Do you have any suggestion about that ?

Comment: Also i use virtaulenvironment

Comment: The entire library needs to be there because the `read_excel()` function could be calling any part of it, directly or indirectly. You can't just separate out that one function.

Comment: Thank you , in my code if i write "import pandas" then using "auto-py-to-exe" to make my code executable it becomes 1Gb. if i do not write "import pandas" and use the same library to make executable it becomes 46Mb is it normal ?