# How do I compile python code with pandas and numpy that results in a small binary?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, compilation, nuitka

I have compiled some python code that uses pandas and numpy. There are no other external dependencies. I compiled with nuitka using the following command:

```
python -m nuitka --onefile code.py
```

The resulting binary is 584 MB. This size inhibits any practical use. I know it is theoretically possible to remove pandas and numpy code and rewrite it all using only python, but then I lose all the obvious benefits of pandas and numpy. As pandas and numpy are super common, how do people get around this?

Comment: The typical suggestion is to create an empty environment and only install what you absolutely need prior to building you executable.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692213/reducing-size-of-pyinstaller-exe